# How to extract elements from a list within a pandas column and append them to a set

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with a column called `df[categories]` that looks like the following:

```
0         ['ACCESSORIES', 'AUDIO', 'LOUNGE']
1         ['ACCESSORIES', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'VISUAL']
2         ['BEDROOM SUITES', 'COMPUTERS', 'COMPUTERS', 'HOME OFFICE', 'HOME OFFICE', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'VISUAL']
3         ['BEDDING', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES']
4         [PATIO]
5         ['MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES']
6         ['ACCESSORIES', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES', 'VISUAL', 'VISUAL']
```

I need to iterate over the entire column of 37000 rows and append every item into a set because I don't want repeating values. I've tried:

```
categories = set()
categories = df['category'].apply(lambda a: set(a))
```

This brings back a pandas series that looks like this:

```
0       {AUDIO, LOUNGE, ACCESSORIES}
1       {MAJOR APPLIANCES, ACCESSORIES, VISUAL}
2       {'BEDROOM SUITES', 'COMPUTERS', 'HOME OFFICE', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'VISUAL'}
3       {'BEDDING', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES'}
4       {PATIO}
5       {'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES'}
6       {'ACCESSORIES', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES', 'VISUAL'}
```

What I actually need as stated above is a single list only containing the unique values like so:

```
[AUDIO, ACCESSORIES, BEDROOM, COMPUTERS,LOUNGE, MAJOR APPLIANCES, ... , VISUAL]
```

Comment: Maybe a set-comp? `categories = {el for row in df['category'] for el in row}`? Then possibly use `list(...)` or `sorted(...)` on that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
set(df['category'].sum())
```

Or this:

```
result = set()
df['category'].apply(result.update)

# Now the result is what you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
categories = [['ACCESSORIES', 'AUDIO', 'LOUNGE'], ['ACCESSORIES', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'VISUAL'], ['BEDROOM SUITES', 'COMPUTERS', 'COMPUTERS', 'HOME OFFICE', 'HOME OFFICE', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'VISUAL'], ['BEDDING', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES'], ['PATIO'], ['MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES'], ['ACCESSORIES', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'MAJOR APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES', 'SMALL APPLIANCES', 'VISUAL', 'VISUAL']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': categories})

print('pandas', pd.__version__)

sorted(set(df.category.explode()))
```

Result:

```
pandas 0.25.3

['ACCESSORIES',
 'AUDIO',
 'BEDDING',
 'BEDROOM SUITES',
 'COMPUTERS',
 'HOME OFFICE',
 'LOUNGE',
 'MAJOR APPLIANCES',
 'PATIO',
 'SMALL APPLIANCES',
 'VISUAL']
```

Comment: I get `Series' object has no attribute 'explode`

Comment: @Mengezi `Series.explode` was added in version 0.25.0.

Comment: I see, let me update my pandas and try the `explode()` function again